# Convert .XLS to .XLSX in Flutter/Dart

Tags: excel, flutter, dart, xlsx, xls

I'm trying to convert .xls to .xlsx in flutter/dart. I cannot seem to get this done. I have tried using the excel package but that doesn't support .xls .  Any Ideas or workaround would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Has anyone figured this out?